# How to obtain the packet travel time when using http proxy server?

Tags: java, networking, social-networking

For example, the destination http server is A, and the proxy server(http) is B. For obtaining the responce time to A directly from my machine is easy. But how am I able to obtain the travel time when using proxy server B? Which mean the travel time include from my machine to B PLUS proxy server B to A. I have no idea how to do the last part which is "proxy server B to A".

I am planning to use Java to solve this problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a request to A through the proxy?  I.e., the normal use of the proxy.  Then the RTT presumably includes both the client <-> B and B <-> A legs.  of course, the proxy might be caching, in which case you are only timing client <-> B, but isn't this what you want?

Comment: Hi, thank for your idea. yes, you are right, your idea should work. I was thinking too complicated. But I am still confused how actually proxy server work, for example there is a proxy server 123.123.123.123:8080 , I want to write a Java program to request http service from this proxy server and investigate the responce time. I was thinking the pattern that I request should be like: http://123.123.123.123:8080/index.php?url=www.google.com. Am my concept correct? How am I going to know the exact URL and parameter?

Comment: No.

HTTP proxies work over HTTP themselves.  You craft a more or less normal http request, and sent it to the proxy, and the proxy knows where to send it, based on the Request-URI.

See the http rfc (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) for details.  You could certainly target an http proxy itself, using say the Max-Forwards header, using an http library.  You might need one more advanced than the JDK URL classes, however.

Comment: oh. I see. Seen like the protocol between my machine and the proxy server is not http type? After I have craft the http request, how do I send the request item to the proxy? via raw socket connection? or?

Comment: No, as above the protocol between your machine and the http proxy _is_ HTTP.